# Play sound in windows phone 8.1 background

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing an app which require background music. Below is my code which i made after searching different forums.

```
class AudioPlayer : IBackgroundTask
{
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstance_Canceled;
    }
    private void TaskInstance_Canceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        _deferral.Complete();
    }

    //===========================================================================================================
    public void startTick()
    {
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(new Uri("ms-appx:///Audio/clock.wav"));
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
    }
}
```

Problem is it doesnt work. No sound from emulator. Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things that might have gone wrong (I guess it's not all your code). The best would be here if you would follow [Bacground Audio Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx).

Please also check if you had added needed declarations (I suspect that this may be a problem here): go to your `Package.appxmanifest` file, open <kbd>Declarations</kbd> then you should add `Background Tasks` with an `Audio`(as suppoerted task type) and specify its entry point (probably `yournamespace.AudioPlayer`).

Also remember that, as said at MSDN (the link above):

> Your background task starts the first time your app accesses BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current in foreground app code.

I advise to set a breakpoint at `Run` method and you should see if `AudioPlayer` had started. Also remember to provide communication between UI and AudioPalyer - [ToUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer.sendmessagetoforeground.aspx) and [ToPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer.sendmessagetobackground.aspx) (of course if you need it).

You may also want to configure your [SMTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.aspx), so that your AudioPlayer would react to those buttons that show when you hit VolumeControl.

Comment: No actually the problem was in the sound :). I have already configured all of these. and now its working fine. But i have a problem while playing multiple timers to play sounds, timer doesnt response correctly and creating issue, do i have to start a new thread for its discussion?

Comment: @SyedWajahatKareem I think the new thread would be most suitable as it's not related to this one.

Comment: @SyedWajahatKareem It would be also suitable if you had provided an answer to your question and then accept it, so that it was solved.

Comment: Yes.Accepted without any doubt :)

Comment: It also appears that the background task will start the first time you subscribe to `BackgroundMediaPlayer.MessageReceivedFromBackground` event.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Yes, that's true. As I've tried it seems that only *IsMediaPlaying* and *Shutdown* doesn't call the BAP, the rest will start the *Task* as soon as you call it.

Answer (score 0):

To help understanding the correct usage of BackgroundMediaPlayer please have a look at [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319) sample,your idea will get cleared.you have to integrate another project's reference to use background Audio.Just have look.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles across this, any IBackgroundTask on Win Phone 8.1 needs to be contained in a WinRT component project type and ***not*** in a class library or PCL.

The MediaPlayer exe will just exit and you'll be left pulling out your hair if you give it a dll.

That and make sure you entry point path is correct in your appxmanifest file and you should be good to go. Just put a breakpoint in your Run() method to verify.